# Cómo desactivar la actualización automática de una extensión en visual studio code

Tags: vscode

Tengo una extensión la cual no me funciona bien con la última versión, por lo que tengo instalada una versión anterior a esta. Pero lo que pasa es que se me actualiza automáticamente a la última versión que no me funciona. ¿Cómo podría desactivar la actualización automática para esta extensión?

Answer (score 0):

Para desactivar la actualización automática debe ingresar a :

Archivo > Preferencias > Configuración

Luego en la parte izquierda del menú seleccionar:

Aplicación > Actualizar

Y en la opción Mode, seleccionar "none"

[image: Desactivar actualización automática]

Answer (score -1):

El funcionamiento normal es que las extensiones se actualicen a la última versión. Si necesitas una versión anterior, puedes instalarla desde el menú de opciones:

[image: Opción para instalar una versión específica]

Una vez instalada una versión específica, ésta se queda fijada (*pinned*) de modo que no se actualizará automáticamente, sólo manualmente:

[image: Extensión con la versión fijada]

Para *desfijar* la versión y que vuelva a autoactualizarse:

[image: Opción para defijar la versión]

Por otro lado, puedes gestionar cómo se hacen las actualizaciones automáticas directamente desde desde el menú de extensiones:

[image: Menú de opciones de las extensiones]